# Bounds for prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's assume that there is always a prime number in the interval $[54n,55n]$ for $n>30$ ($n$ is a natural number).

Using the fact above, find the best upper and lower bounds on prime counting function.

Comment: What have you tried?  Partition $\Bbb N \gt 54 \cdot 30$ into intervals.  Do you want to have them overlap or be disjoint?  It depends on which bound you are working on.

Comment: @RossMillikan I want to have them disjoint.

Comment: @Nilknarf  I would be surprised if there failed to be a prime in $[54n,55n]$ for any $n \gt 6$

Comment: Nvm, just Bertrand's Postulate. :P

Comment: Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323711/prime-number-theory-and-primes-in-a-specific-interval).

Comment: I don't see an easy way to use this to get an upper bound.  You are right, for the lower bound you can just pack as many disjoint intervals like this as you can and count one prime each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $N$ large, each time $\log N$ increases by $\log \frac {55}{54}$ we get at least one new prime, so a lower bound is $$\pi(N) \ge \frac {\log N}{\log \frac {55}{54}}$$
This is very slow growing compared to the $\frac {N}{\log N}$ of the real prime counting function.

Comment: it would be better if we could compute $N$, but thanks for this perspective!

Comment: $N$ is the input for the prime counting function.  It is not surprising that we get a severe undercount as there are often many more than one prime in each interval.  Did you mean you would like a bound proportional to $N$?  We can't have that as it would exceed the prime counting function.